# How do I skip the "Send right mouse click" and just send a right mouse click in teamviewer?

Tags: teamviewer

In the TeamViewer web connect, if you right click you get this:

[image]

Is this possible to disable and just send the click?

Comment: I doubt it is possible as that window you see is "flash" plugin asking if you want to send mouse click, or you actually need the flash settings. So unless somehow you can set it on flash player to ignore right click.... I don't see how. Why not use TeamViewer standalone? (Just download and run - no need to install.. for Windows only I think)

Comment: I only use webconnect on computers I can't install to. All other ones I use the standalone.